# Passing stack string/array to a function

Tags: c

I split a string by

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    char *str, *delm;
    str = "The first part/the second part/still in the second part"; // str comes from within the loop
    delm = "/";

    // The function block
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    char *ptr;
    int pos;
    ptr = strstr(str, delm);
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
      pos = -1;
    }
    else
    {
      pos = ptr - str;
    }

    if (pos > -1)
    {
      char first[pos + 1];
      strncpy(first, str, pos);
      first[pos] = 0;

      char second[len - pos + 1];
      strncpy(second, str + pos + 1, len - pos);
      second[len - pos] = 0;

      // end of the block

      printf("%s - %s\n", first, second);
    }
  }
}
```

Since I often use this process, it is beneficial to define a function to make the code easy to read:

```
void split(const char *str, const char *delm, char *first, char *second){

// the code

}
```

In this case, I need to define the variables `first` and `second` dynamically via `malloc` and `realloc` since their sizes are not known outside the function. This may impact the performance (though the function may also do).

In general, I am curious if there is a trick for executing a function with output on the stack?

Comment: There is also `strtok()`

Comment: You can have the caller pass a buffer to use for output. In the case of `split`, the maximum buffer size is at most the size of the input string, so the caller merely needs to pass a buffer of the same size (or can let `split` use the input array as the output array). `split` can put the first string at the start of the output buffer (so the caller already knows where it is) and return the address where the second string starts in the buffer.

Comment: @Déjàvu how do you use `strtok()` for capturing the second part when there are still delimiters therein?